# Magento 2 : Responsive Logo

Tags: magento2, luma-theme, logo

I have Magento 2.1.4 with Luma theme. Is there any way for logo / yellow banner to resize accordingly on mobiles altering the css? This is what it looks right now[image]

Comment: Share your URL here. Have you tried width=100%; for image ?

Comment: www.legowatches.com.au - The width is already 100%, but the logo needs to be smaller on mobiles, is there any way to do that?